# Prove that $\exp\left(-\frac{5}{2} \sum_{s = 1}^t \frac{1}{s}\right) \leq \frac{\exp(5/2)}{1 + t}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

As part of a proof I am working on, I need to show that

\begin{align*}
\exp\left(-\frac{5}{2} \sum_{s = 1}^t \frac{1}{s}\right) \leq \frac{\exp(5/2)}{1 + t}.
\end{align*}

This appears to be true by looking at the graph. I have tried taking the log of both sides, and looking at the inequalities

\begin{align*}
\sum_{s = 1}^t \frac{1}{s} &\leq 1 + \log(t)\\
\exp\left(\sum_{s = 1}^t \frac{1}{s}\right) &\geq 1 + t
\end{align*}

but I'm not sure how to use them to prove the desired inequality.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

One can prove that the harmonic numbers $H_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ satisfy $H_n \geq \ln(n+1)$ for all $n$ using Riemann sums. Setting $c = 5/2$, we then have
$$ \exp(-cH_t) \leq \exp(-c\ln(t+1)) = (t+1)^{-c}$$
so it suffices to show that
$$ (t+1)^{-c} \leq \frac{e^c}{1+t}.$$
This is certainly true for $ c > 1$.

Out of curiosity, what's the original problem?